# How to resolve "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1" error on TypeScript React Hook useState()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to create a custom hook called `useForm` using `useState()`.

Following is the code for `useForm`:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

interface valuesInterface {
    email: string
    password: string
}

export const useForm = (initialValue: valuesInterface) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<valuesInterface>(initialValue);

    return [
        values,
        (e: { target: { name: any; value: any; }; }) => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            })
        }
    ]
};
```

I import that function into my main `App`:

```
import {useForm} from './utils/useForm';
import './App.css';

interface valuesInterface {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

const App = () => {
  const [values, handleChange] = useForm<valuesInterface>({email: '', password: ''});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name='email' value={values.email} onChange={handleChange}/>
      <input type='password' name='password' value={values.password} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I've defined the **interface** `valuesInterface` to describe the data shape as an object. I'm not if I've done it properly, though. However, my error seems to have something to do with the parameters.

**Error**:

```
Failed to compile.

/frontend/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in 
/frontend/src/App.tsx(10,42):
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.  TS2558

     8 | 
     9 | const App = () => {
  > 10 |   const [values, handleChange] = useForm<valuesInterface>({email: '', password: ''});
       |                                          ^
    11 | 
    12 |   return (
    13 |     <div className="App">
```

Have I defined the type correctly, and am I utilising it as it should be in my custom hook?

Thanks! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you copy the definition of `valuesInterface` in different files? Also `useForm` is not a generic function, remove the `<valuesInterface>` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useForm` hook isn't a generic function.

Workaround:

```
// file: useForm

import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export const useForm = <T extends Record<string, unknown>(initialState: T) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<T>(initialState);

    return [
        values,
        useCallback((event: { target: { name: string; value: unknown; }; }) => {
            setValues(v => ({ ...v, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        }, [])
    ]
};
```